# Different timestamps on different servers

Tags: php

I run this simple php statement on two different servers:

```
echo time();
```

The first server's `date();` function returns: Thu Oct 16 15:36:11 EDT 2014
The second server's `date();` function returns: Thu Oct 16 19:36:59 UTC 2014

The timestamps on the two servers are off by exactly 17 seconds. I understand that timestamp can be different depending on the server's timezone seconds. But how is the difference exactly  17 seconds even though one server is on EDT and the other is on UTC?

Comment: The servers could just become off naturally, look into the syncing the time with a reliable source. For Linux, see this article: http://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-sync-your-linux-server-time-with-network-time-servers-ntp/

Comment: One or both servers are not syncing their time to NTP servers often enough, or at all. The clock in the average computer/server can be fairly imprecise and gain/lose seconds over time. I've seen some servers that float by several seconds each day if NTP is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: the time of the server is set differently. Servers do not know the time magically: they need to either be set by someone, or have a service (ntp for instance) changing the time.

One of the servers (or both) is just not set correctly. Just like a slow watch.

Comment: Curious, why a minus 1 on this?

Comment: I don't know, but this is correct. A list of [ntpdate](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/) servers that can be used to synchronize time as well.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that one or both of your servers are not synchronizing their clocks to the same, maybe any, network time protocol (**NTP**) server.

If both servers are synchronizing to an **NTP** service, they should both report the same time, allowing for time zone differences.

You don't mention which OS you're running.  In various *nix flavors, you would want to run **ntpdate** periodically to sync your time.  Some folks have a scheduled task to do this once a week or day.  I've seen it done hourly.

[NTP.org](http://www.ntp.org/) is the place to go to learn more about the **NTP** service.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set a timezone for you application so it is the same across all pages, regardless of the server. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php:

`date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

Heres a list of [supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: That will not help the 17 secs the OP is asking about though

Comment: Sure it will ! If he explicitly sets the time zone, the time/date function will output the exact same time, across his application, which is what he wants.

Comment: no, it will output the same time-zone-adjusted-time, based on the time the server reported. If the server has a bad idea of what date it is, it can do +8 all it wants but never get those seconds back.

Comment: Nanne is correct....setting timezone on both servers is still returning the same result...the timestamps are off by 17 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by modifying the .htaccess file

php_value date.timezone "Europe/Berlin"

You can change ""Europe/Berlin" to whatever timezone you want like America/Los_Angeles etc. Once you will add that it will show the same timezone. No matter on which server you are.

Here is the list of supported timezones you can choose form http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php